# Should I use my personal Apple ID for development or create a new one?

Tags: itunes, accounts, developer-program

I'm about ready to release my first iOS app. While I was going through the steps to register in the development program I became unsure.

Should I set up a new iTunes account to publish my app under, or do I just use my existing personal one that I use for my games, music, etc.?

I read somewhere that whatever account you use gets a bit of spam, how do users get your email address?

Comment: That thing about spam, it’s plain rumours.

Comment: Thanks, that at least is good to know. Are there any other considerations to take into account?

Comment: Nope. You are pretty much set up. Use your personal ID.

Comment: @duci9y I believe the "spam rumour" is related to the fact that the email address you provide *for support emails* gets a lot of spam, because it's made available on the iTunes Store pages for your app. Whether iTunes Connect uses the email from your Apple ID or whether you can specify it separately, I don't know, but using a dedicated address for your support email does seem like a good policy.

Comment: @DanJ You are right. I believe the support email address is optional. Most big-shot developers don’t include their support email address. Instead they redirect to a web form.

Comment: It is a year later now, I used my own email address, and I have not had any issues with it yet.

Comment: it is another year later now. what about in terms of test deployment - any issues when deploying to a personal device associated to the personal apple account?

Comment: @ronaldwidha I've let my developer account expire, but I don't recall having any issues. I tested on my own device and on a few others and can't recall anything happening that I wasn't happy with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a hard and fast rule, or many convincing arguments in either direction. However, if you eventually want to make money or work with others, or in general grow in that direction, you may find that the ability to keep your personal and work stuff separate to be helpful.

A simple example may be that you have personal pictures on iCloud associated with your personal ID, and for whatever reason, you want to give someone complete access to your development account without access to iCloud. Yes, there are other ways to accomplish that, but having the option of two different Apple IDs might come in helpful down the road.